# IDAPython can't ignore library functions

Tags: ida, idapython

I wrote a simple IDAPython script that only prints out local functions and ignores library functions. But somehow, it prints every single function. Here is the script:

```
import idc, idautils
for func in idautils.Functions():
    flags = idc.GetFunctionFlags(func)
    # Ignore library functons
    if flags & FUNC_LIB:
        continue
    print idc.GetFunctionName(func)
```

I based my script from the second code snippet in this tutorial (http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2016/06/unit42-using-idapython-to-make-your-life-easier-part-6/).

Comment: Try checking the segment: idc.SegName(start) != 'extern'

Comment: Thank you, your method works. Just to elaborate for anyone else interested. Aside from 'extern,' I also need to make sure that segment name is not ".plt," ".init," or ".fini." So to simplify the code, I just check if segment name equals ".text" or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a confusion of terminology.  In IDA-speak, "library function" means "a function from a (compiler) standard library", i.e. a function recognised by a FLIRT signature (usually colored in cyan). These are encountered in practice mostly in statically-linked Windows executables. On Linux and OS X the standard functions usually come from shared libraries so you will need another way to distinguish them - e.g. what what was suggested in the comments.